# Show $(URU^* - \lambda I)^jv = 0 \Rightarrow (R - \lambda I_n)^jU^*v = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand a small step in a proof. Could anyone show me why this is true?
If $U$ is a unitary matrix and $R$ an upper triangle matrix show that for $j \geq 1$:
$$
(URU^* - \lambda I)^jv = 0 \Rightarrow (R - \lambda I_n)^jU^*v = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(URU^*-\lambda I)^jv=(URU^*-\lambda UU^*)^jv=(U(R-\lambda I)U^*)^jv=U(R-\lambda I)^jU^*v$

**Added**

In fact, $UABU^*=(UAU^*)(UBU^*)$, therefore $(UAU^*)^n=UA^nU^*$

Comment: Thanks! This made everything clear.